# How can I change the underlying points coordinate space of the iPad in such a way, that 1 point equals 2 pixels?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How can I change the underlying points coordinate space of the iPad in such a way, that 1 point equals 2 pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a `CGAffineTransformScale` to whatever view you are using:

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(myView.transform, 2.0, 2.0);
```

Here is a great blog post on the use of transforms:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html

Answer (score 1):

hum!

```
static __inline__ CGPoint CGPointMake2(CGFloat x, CGFloat y)
{
  CGPoint p; 
  p.x = x*2; // twice the pixels.
  p.y = y*2; 
  return p;
}
```